# Using Oracle SQL-Function JSON_EXISTS in JPQL

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpa, jpql

In my Oracle-database table *mytable* I have a column *columnx* with JSON-Arrays (VARCHAR2) and I would like to find all entries where the value *valueX* is inside that array.

In native Oracle-SQL the following query is working very well:
`SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE JSON_EXISTS(columnx, '$?(@ == "valueX")');`

In my Spring Boot Application I write queries in JPQL, so I have to convert it.

The following queries were unsuccessful:

1. I found out that I have to use 'FUNCTION()' for specific SQL-Oracle-functions:
   `@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM mytable t WHERE FUNCTION('JSON_EXISTS',t.columnx, '$?(@ == \"valueX\")')")`
   That results in a JPQL-Parsing-Error:  "QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: function (JSON_EXISTS)"
2. I found out that JPQL needs a real boolean-comparison, so I tried this:
   `@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM mytable t WHERE FUNCTION('JSON_EXISTS',t.columnx, '$?(@ == \"valueX\")') = TRUE")`
   Now the JPQL-Converter can parse it to native SQL successfully, but I got an Oracle-Error while executing the query: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended."
   That's understandable since the parsed native `... WHERE JSON_EXISTS(columnx, '$?(@ == "valueX")') = 1` won't run either.

What is the right way to solve this problem? Do you have any idea?

EDIT:
This is the field definition in JAVA:

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
public class Mytable {
    ...
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2")
    private List<String> columnx;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below using native query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE 
JSON_EXISTS(columnx, '$?(@ == \"valueX\")')", 
nativeQuery = true)
```

OR You can hide the JSON_EXISTS implementation inside a view in oracle and call the view in JPQL.

```
    create or replace view my_table_json_exists as SELECT * FROM 
    mytable t WHERE 
    JSON_EXISTS(t.columnx, '$?(@ == "valueX")');

   @Query(value ="select t from my_table_json_exists t");
```

If you are only looking for valueX inside a json key then you can explore **JSON_VALUE**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, the native query works fine, but I can't use it, because there is a complex filtering system in querydsl with a set of dynamic parameters, so that I need the JPQL form. Unfortunately the JPQL with your CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE cannot be parsed and I get this exception: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because the return value of "antlr.collections.AST.getNextSibling()" is null`

Comment: Can you share one sample data with valueX from your JSON column

Answer (score 1):

In JPQL use `MEMBER OF` operator to check if a value is contained in a JSON array stored in a column. The JPQL query would look something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM mytable t WHERE :valueX MEMBER OF t.columnx")
List<Mytable> findByValueX(@Param("valueX") String valueX);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That JPQL get parsed to `... WHERE 'valueX' in (SELECT ...)` which returns in Oarcle-DB an empty list, because the column-type is VARCHAR2. Oracle doesn't look inside the Array.

Comment: What exactly you see inside that `(SELECT ..)`?